# why is audio tag not working after refresh page

Tags: vue.js

The audio tag works fine when i open the page via router-link(from another page), however if i refresh this current page with audio tag, audio didn't reload, is there anything that i need to add or change? or i should try other method than audio to play audio files?

Below are my code:

Should I try another method to play .mp3 files?

```
<template lang="pug">
    audio#player(autoplay="" loop="")
        source(src="@/assets/alertsound.mp3" type="audio/mp3")
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure whats causing this exactly but there is another way you can play your audio ...this will trigger the audio `load()` :

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted: function() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs.audio.load()
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <audio ref="audio" autoplay loop>
         <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Example.ogg"
                 type="audio/ogg"
         > 
    </audio>
  </div>
</div>
```